# Is the following function finite?

Tags: limits, functions

Let $1 < p < 2$ and $\forall \ \xi \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ sucht that
$$\varphi (\xi) = \frac{|1 + \xi|^p - 1 - p \xi}{|\xi|^p}.$$
We have that $$\lim_{\xi \to \pm \infty} \varphi (\xi) = 1 \;\; ; \;\; \lim_{\xi \to 0} \;\; \varphi (\xi) = 0.$$
Is $\varphi (\xi)$ finite for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$?
Why yes / no?

Thank you!

Comment: $$\lim_{\xi \to 0} \;\; \varphi (\xi) \neq  0.$$

Comment: As long as $\xi\not=0$ then you're not dividing by zero so it is finite.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ Gregory Grant: Consider the left limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\xi > -1$, we have $1 + \xi > 0$, hence $\lvert 1+\xi\rvert^p = (1+\xi)^p$, and by second order Taylor expansion,

$$(1+\xi)^p = 1 + p\xi + \frac{p(p-1)(1+\vartheta\xi)^{p-2}}{2}\xi^2$$

for some $\vartheta \in (0,1)$.

Therefore,

$$\frac{\lvert 1+\xi\rvert^p - 1 - p\xi}{\lvert\xi\rvert^p} = \frac{p(p-1)(1+\vartheta\xi)^{p-2}}{2}\lvert\xi\rvert^{2-p},$$

and we see that $\lim\limits_{\xi \to 0} \varphi(\xi) = 0$.

Since $\lim\limits_{\lvert\xi\rvert\to\infty} \varphi(\xi) = 1$, it follows that $\varphi$ is bounded.

Comment: Why does $\vartheta$ appear? By Taylor expansion we have $$(1 + \xi)^p = 1 + p \xi + \frac{p (p - 1)(1 + \xi)^{p - 2}}{2} \xi^2.$$

Comment: The second derivative is evaluated strictly between the centre of development and the point in question, $$f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a)\cdot h + \frac{f''(a +\vartheta\cdot h)}{2}h^2.$$ That is the Lagrange form of the remainder term. Check with $f(x) = x^3$ and $a = 0$, then you have $f(h) = f(0) + f'(0)\cdot h + \frac{f''(h/3)}{2}\cdot h^2$.